# Split image in CSS?

Tags: css, image

I'm trying to edit some CSS (on a tumblr page) and I'm having a problem with an icon. It's the Twitter icon on the far right of this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbMiz.png)

[image]

Above appears as split in half on the page.

I used the code below for all four of the icons ((just a different url for each image), yet I'm not sure why the Twitter one is split like that.

#### What could be the reason and how can I fix it?

Code:

```
#above-nav-links a.twitter:before {
    background-image: url(http://imgh.us/twitter_icon_blue.svg);
    content: ' ';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

If you copy-paste the background-image url, you can see the image I used for the icon (it is not split). The pages I used for the other icons are similar (in terms of spacing, size, etc.).

Comment: Try adding float:left; property in css

Comment: Additionally, does anybody know why the "repeat: no-repeat" line is there? It's part of the theme's default code, but "repeat" doesn't seem to be a CSS property. Also, although it's set to no-repeat, if I change the width and height of the image I can see that it still repeats. The editor still highlights it as it would any other property, though.

Comment: Please show your complete code with HTML and CSS so we can understand better what's wrong your code

Comment: There are 1607 lines, hence it's too long to post. What specific part do you need to see?

Comment: Ok let me put some code for you. Hope you will change your code accordingly.

Comment: @Ted. The `repeat: no-repeat;` is not a correct CSS property. It should be in the form of `background-repeat: no-repeat`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference. Here's an article about it that explains it well: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-repeat/

Comment: @stubben That's what I thought, thank you. I did not write this code, it was in the original tumblr theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I havn't seen your code, you can change your code accordingly

```
<ul id="#icons">
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
<style type="text/css">
#icons > li
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
}
#icons > li > a
{
    background-image: url("icons.png");
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    repeat: no-repeat;
}
#icons > li:nth-child(1) > a
{
    background-position:2px -8px;
}
#icons > li:nth-child(2) > a
{
    background-position:-29px -8px;
}
#icons > li:nth-child(3) > a
{
    background-position:-61px -8px;
}
#icons > li:nth-child(4) > a
{
    background-position:-97px -7px;
}
</style>
```

Background-positions are set according to my icon image. You may need to udpate as per your image.

Comment: background-position:left seemed to work, thanks! I added it in the line under repeat. 
float:left did not work.

Comment: Note: @Abdul You edited your response, but the original response worked (you suggested background-position:left). I think you removed that part, though. Otherwise I would click the check mark!

Comment: Actually I was trying to give a better idea when handling split images.  Background-position left is good but its better to tell the exact position of image in split image. Rest is upto you.